# Alternative for using video element on drawImage IOS Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, canvas, react-hooks

Apparently Safari on IOS doesn't support video element as a source for **drawImage**

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkitjs/canvasrenderingcontext2d/1630282-drawimage

I want to implement a blurred background for a video using the video element. If there is an alternative for **imageDraw**?, would there any alternative to implement the same feature? Or perhaps a different approach?

Here is what I have so far, it works on all browsers except Safari on IOS.

```
import { useLayoutEffect, useRef, useCallback } from 'react';

const useVideoBlurredOverlay = () => {
    const videoRef = useRef(null);
    const overlayRef = useRef(null);
    const requestAnimationRef = useRef(null);

    const animateOverlay = useCallback((video, canvasContext) => {
        const canvasClientWidth = canvasContext.canvas.clientWidth;
        const canvasClientHeight = canvasContext.canvas.clientHeight;

        // Bail when video is full width
        if (canvasClientWidth <= video.clientWidth)
            return false;

        // Prevent black flash
        if (video.currentTime === 0)
            return false;

        canvasContext.canvas.width = canvasClientWidth;
        canvasContext.canvas.height = canvasClientHeight;

        // Stretch
        canvasContext.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvasClientWidth, canvasClientHeight);

        return null;
    }, []);

    const handleOverlay = useCallback((video, canvasContext) => {
        if (video.paused || video.ended)
            return false;

        animateOverlay(video, canvasContext);
        requestAnimationRef.current = requestAnimationFrame(() => handleOverlay(video, canvasContext));

        return null;
    }, [ animateOverlay ]);

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        const video = videoRef.current;
        const overlay = overlayRef.current;

        if (video && overlay) {
            const canvasContext = overlay.getContext('2d');
            video.addEventListener('play', () => handleOverlay(video, canvasContext));
        }

        return () => {
            video.removeEventListener('play', handleOverlay);
        };
    }, [ videoRef, overlayRef, handleOverlay ]);

    return {
        videoRef,
        overlayRef
    };
};

export default useVideoBlurredOverlay;
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Not really. I ended up using a fallback image for IOS Safari and kept this same implementation.